# BEM Notation & SLDS Validator

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds, bemnotation

With the [BEM Notation change](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_slds_bem_deprecate.htm&type=5&release=230) being enforced in Summer 21, what's the best way to search the code base for any references requiring updating?

I've tried to use `class=".*--.*"` and `.*--.*` while searching within VSCodebut these return no results, yet I know there are items such as:

```
padding-bottom: var(--lwc-spacingMedium,1rem);
.THIS .slds-box--xxx-small
class="slds-size--small"
```

I am misunderstanding what needs to be updated, or searching incorrectly?

The SLDS validator doesn't seem to work for me and I was hoping for something that could scan the code base...

Answer (score 1):

I'd search-and-replace:

```
slds-([a-z0-9-]+?)--
```

With:

```
slds-$1_
```

Make sure you enable the RegExp search mode (the far-right icon in the search box).

But you'll still need to do a manual review to make sure you don't accidentally get anything you didn't mean to.

Comment: Because the "-" is at the end of the character group there's no need to escape it. Also, there's no call, that I can see, for the "?" either.

Comment: @PhilW you're right on the first count, but the ? Is actually in case you have multiple CSS styles in the same line of code. It's probably superfluous, but would save search time by being "not greedy".

Comment: In the case of multiple old-style BEM classes you would find whitespace between them so the match would not actually cross the divide... :D